How to access Firestore locally for testing in pure Dart without Flutter?
I'm developing a Flutter application and want to implement unit tests that involve Firestore operations. I'm looking for a way to access Firestore emulator locally for testing purposes.(Use pure dart on command line.)
What I Want to Achieve

Set up a local Firestore emulator for testing
Connect to this local instance from my Dart tests
Perform CRUD operations against the local Firestore instance
Reset the database state between tests

Questions

Is it possible to connect to a local Firestore emulator using pure Dart?
If yes, what configuration or setup is required?
Are there any specific packages or approaches recommended for this use case?


Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

use fake_cloud_firestore package
